# How does Angular respond with a dynamic and raw JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, webserver, response

If a JSON file is put under assets, calling something like `http://localhost:4200/myapp.com/assets/hello.json` will retrieve the JSON file as is, without the GUI. That means Angular should know how to return a raw JSON object.

Now, instead of a static JSON file, I would like to create a JSON object content so that Angular will return a dynamic JSON object. For example, `http://localhost:4200/echo?input=world` will return `{"hello": "world"}`

**Updated use case based on comment received**:
The real use case here is I have a 3rd party independent frontend app, which I embed it with my Angular app and display it in an Angular component using iFrame. However, this embedded app requires some data for customizing the display for the user dynamically. We can do this by calling API but this requires a unnecessary call to the backend as the Angular app has already got that information, plus there is a cost incurred to call the backend.

Hence I would like to see if there is a shortcut to let the embedded app calling the parent Angular. Maybe my question should be "How can a **webserver** return a raw JSON object based on the query string"

Comment: Loading the URL `http://localhost:4200/myapp.com/assets/hello.json` is completely unrelated to Angular. The browser requests this JSON file from the webserver. Angular isn't involved. This looks like an XY question. What are you actually trying to achieve? I think Angular is the wrong approach.

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to viewing the data as a JSON object? If that is the case, Angular has a JSON pipe for this: https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe - ex: {{apiResponse | json}}

Comment: The real use case here is I have a 3rd party independent app embedded inside my parent Angular app using iFrame. However, this embedded app requires some data to customize the display correctly. We can do this by calling back API but this requires a unnecessary call to the backend as the Angular app has already got the information. Hence I would like to see if there is a short cut to let the embedded app calling the parent Angular. Maybe my question should be "How can a **webserver** return a raw JSON object based on the query string"

Comment: You should create a API based on Angular. This requires the client to interpret JavaScript. Most API clients won't do it. It won't work. You should completely avoid Angular and do all of this in the backend. Assuming you use Angular for this: The client has to load all the Angular framework from the webserver and evaluate the JavaScript on the local computer for each API call. That's a huge waste of bandwidth and time.

Comment: The edit looks like a completely different question. Please ask only one question per question. Your original question was answered. The webserver is unrelated to Angular. It only serves the static files. Angular is evaluated on the client.

Answer (score 1):

With a combination of [queryParamMap](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) and [json pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe) to display dynamic json

[Here is a stackblitz implementation of json pipe](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-phwyr1?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Here is the code using the url params to get the json path and the input you want to add in the json.

Example url: http://localhost:4200/echo?input=world&jsonPath=hello.json

```
import { Component, inject, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { firstValueFrom, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'echo',
    template: `<div>{{ jsonData | json }}</div>`,
})
export class Echo implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private http = inject(HttpClient);
    private queryParamSubscription: Subscription;
    private readonly activatedRoute = inject(ActivatedRoute);

    jsonData: any;

    async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
        this.queryParamSubscription =
            this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap.subscribe(async (map): Promise<void> => {
                const input = map.get('input') as string;
                // Pretend input contains 'world'

                const jsonPath = map.get('jsonPath') as string;
                // Pretend jsonPath contains 'hello.json'

                const jsonFileData = await this.getJsonData(jsonPath);

                // Pretend hello.json contains { "hello": "" }
                jsonFileData.hello = input;
                // Now contains { "hello": "world" }

                this.jsonData = jsonFileData;
            });
    }

    getJsonData(jsonPath: string): Promise<any> {
        return firstValueFrom(this.http.get<any>(`assets/${jsonPath}`));
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        if (this.queryParamSubscription) {
            this.queryParamSubscription.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's important to mention that this won't work as an API, because it requires JavaScript to be evaluated. But since that's not asked in the question, your answer correctly answers the question.

Comment: @jabaa yeah its more like a dirty custom data visualizer, certainly not an API, you are right

Comment: @TheSegfault The real use case here is I have a 3rd party independent app embedded inside my parent Angular app using iFrame. However, this embedded app requires some data to customize the display correctly. We can do this by calling back API but this requires a unnecessary call to the backend as the Angular app has already got the information. Hence I would like to see if there is a shortcut to let the embedded app calling the parent Angular to save the cost calling the backend. Therefore, I don't need a GUI to display the JSON, but need the JSON to be returned like it's fetched from /assets